# How separated is a submetrizable space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

A space is submetrizable if its topology contains a coarser metrizable topology.

Each such space is Hausdorff: given two points $x,y$, the sets $B_{|x-y|/2}(x),B_{|x-y|/2}(y)$ are open in the space.

How far can this be strengthened? To $T_3$? To [functionally Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000009)? To [$T_{2.5}$](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000004)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be strengthened to $T_3$.  Here's an example (which Munkres called $\mathbb{R}_K$).  Let $K = \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and let $\tau$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the usual open intervals and the sets of the form $(a, b) \setminus K$.  Obviously this is finer than the usual metric topology, so it is submetrizable by your definition.  But in this topology $K$ is closed and cannot be separated from $0$ by open sets.

It can be strengthened to functionally Hausdorff (and hence also to $T_{2.5}$).  In fact, if $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on $X$ with $\tau_1$ finer than $\tau_2$, and $f : X \to [0, 1]$ is continuous with respect to $\tau_2$, then $f$ is also continuous with respect to $\tau_1$.

Comment: Nice writeup. Note $K$ can be any non-Euclidean-closed subset to get what we want. In particular, https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000058 and https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000059 are both examples of non-regular (in fact, non-semiregular) spaces which are submetrizable.